# jQuery .live() not working inside document ready

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Before updating jquery mobile on a site from version: v1.0b1 to the present: 1.2.0, this worked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.ui-page').live('pageshow', function(e, ui) {
     // do something
   });
});
```

But after updating this no longer works. But this does:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});

$('.ui-page').live('pageshow', function(e, ui) {
   // do something
});
```

If I take out the code and put it outside dom ready it works. Is there a way to make it work inside the dom ready?

Comment: By any chance are you dynamically creating the element?

Comment: You should never use $(document).ready() with jQuery Mobile. That fact is well documented in the api documentation. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html Also, there is no point in having an event bound with .live inside of a document.ready, the document doesn't have to be ready to bind an element to the document itself.

Comment: what version of the jquery are you using ?

Comment: @insomiac jquery-1.8.1.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `$(document).ready()` with `$(document).bind('pageinit')` on jquery mobile.

### Important: Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not $(document).ready()

The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the `$(document).ready()` function so everything will execute as soon as the DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the `pageinit` event. This event is explained in detail at the bottom of this page.

For more details, refer **[JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html)**

Comment: `$(document).bind('pageinit')` is not the same thing as `$(document).ready()`. The difference is that the former will fire for every pseudo-page initialized, which could potentially be dozens of times for a large website. The latter will fire once per page-load, and the former will fire once per pseudo-page-load (which occurs many times in the same DOM). Just keep this in mind, you may need to target specific pages with your `pageinit` event handler: `$(document).on('pageinit', '#myPageID', function () { ... });`